# Java - How to initialize stack use another existing stack?

Tags: java, android, stack

I already using `Stack` what using class type for `TOKEN`, and now I want to make and initialize new `Stack` using stack on first.

First I think C#'s code, like

`Stack<Token> e_infixTokens = new Stack<Token>(infixTokens);`

C#'s Stack constuctor use another stack to parameter, but I think JAVA doesn't. Am I right?

So, Here is begin part of my code,

```
private Stack<Token> infixTokens;
private Stack<Token> postfixTokens;

Formula(String formula){
    this.formula = formula;
    this.infixTokens = new Stack<>();
    this.postfixTokens = new Stack<>();
```

And few lines under, I use this statement.

```
Stack<Token> e_infixTokens = new Stack<>(infixTokens);
```

It occurs error. Error message is :

> Stack() in Stack cannot be applied to Java.util.Stack

Comment: Not entirely clear what you're looking for. Do you want the new stack (`e_infixTokens`) to be the same `Stack` as `infixTokens`?  or do you want to make a new `Stack` that is a copy of `infixTokens`? Some clarification would be nice for the non-C# users.

Comment: Try reading the javadoc for the classes you are using. You got a list of all available ctors and methods there.

Answer (score 1):

One simple method is like this.

```
Stack<String> stackCopy = (Stack<String>) stack1.clone();
```

This method is from java.util.Vector.clone(), so it's probably a fast  implementation.

Another one is like this, which is very slow after testing.

```
Stack<String> stackCopy = new Stack<String>();
for (String string : stack) {
    stackCopy2.add(string);
}
```

The following snippet compares the performance of the two methods to initialize stack by another existing stack.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        stack.push("" + i);
    }


    {
        Stack<String> stackCopy = null;
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final int numIterations = 100000;
        for (int i = 0; i < numIterations; i++) {
            stackCopy = (Stack<String>) stack.clone();
        }
        System.out.println("stackCopy.get(0) 1 = " + stackCopy.get(0));

        long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
        System.out.println("Time taken for this: "
                + (millis > 100000 ? (millis / 1000) + " seconds." : millis + " milliseconds."));
    }
    {
        Stack<String> stackCopy = null;
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final int numIterations = 100000;
        for (int i = 0; i < numIterations; i++) {
            stackCopy = new Stack<String>();
            for (String string : stack) {
                stackCopy.add(string);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("stackCopy.get(0) 2 = " + stackCopy.get(0));

        long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
        System.out.println("Time taken for this: "
                + (millis > 100000 ? (millis / 1000) + " seconds." : millis + " milliseconds."));
    }
}
```

The console result is as follows:

```
stackCopy.get(0) 1 = 0
Time taken for this: 70 milliseconds.
stackCopy.get(0) 2 = 0
Time taken for this: 4098 milliseconds.
```

In addition, the speeds of calling 'add' and calling 'push' are similar in the second method.